# Unable to resolve module for Apollo Client version 3

Tags: react-native, apollo-client

I just upgraded to `apollo/client` version 3

[image]

I have removed all other apollo dependnecies like `apollo hooks`  etc and I am importing everything from the `apollo/client` itself.

My `App.js` file looks as follows in my `react native` project

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'apollo/client';
import TodoStack from './src/components/TodoStack';
import client from './src/client/ApolloClient';

export default () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <TodoStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

But when I run my app I get an error saying

[image]

I tried removing following steps as well

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
yarn start --reset-cache
rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

Comment: import `ApolloProvider` from `import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';`

Comment: @KishanBharda Does not work. Same problem. Take a look at this video https://youtu.be/dlKzlksOUtU?t=187 I am doing the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import ApolloProvider from  '@apollo/client' instead of 'apollo/client'.

The **@** is important here.

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {ApolloProvider} from '@apollo/client';
import TodoStack from './src/components/TodoStack';
import client from './src/client/ApolloClient';

export default () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <TodoStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for offtopic, but I had similar error with correct `@apollo/client`.

```
While trying to resolve module `@apollo/client/link/ws` from file `/media/nvme/pro/virtual_coach/coach-expo/plugins/graphqlClient.ts`, the packag
e `/media/nvme/pro/virtual_coach/coach-expo/node_modules/@apollo/client/link/ws/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itsel
f specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/media/nvme/pro/virtual_coach/coach-expo/node_modules/@apollo/client/link/ws/ws.cj
s`. Indeed, none of these files exist:                                  

  * /media/nvme/pro/virtual_coach/coach-expo/node_modules/@apollo/client/link/ws/ws.cjs(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|
.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * /media/nvme/pro/virtual_coach/coach-expo/node_modules/@apollo/client/link/ws/ws.cjs/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx
|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
```

---

I posting solution for other that have this strange error message.

---

I compared corect package.json from `/node_modules/@apollo/client/link/ws/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@apollo/client/link/ws",
  "main": "ws.cjs.js",
  "module": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

with `package.json` that throw error

```
{
  "name": "@apollo/client/link/ws",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "ws.cjs",
  "module": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

In error message there is a long list of possible extensions. But without `.cjs`. In project where I can see error there are files in package directory

```
index.d.ts  index.d.ts.map  index.js  index.js.map  package.json  ws.cjs  ws.cjs.map
```

but in correct project there is also `wc.cjs.js`.

---

So probably in new package version build js file was removed and because of not package.json hat `type`: `module`.

Finally i downgraded `@apollo/client` changing version in `package.json` from

```
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.8",
```

to fixed:

```
    "@apollo/client": "3.4.8",
```